# Implementing Threading in python, different behavior on different and similar thread count

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x

I have been implementing threads for the first time.
So i decided to use a list and initiate multiple threads to see how it works.

Here is the code i ran.

```
import threading 

    p = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999,1111,22222,44444,566666,877889528]


    def create_workers():
        for _ in range(1):
            t = threading.Thread(target = work)
            t.daemon  =True
            t.start()

    def work():
        for i in range (0,len(p)):
            print (threading.current_thread().name, p[i])
            p.pop(i)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        create_workers()
```

I ran this code with multiple thread count and each time the output is different, different in a way that on thread count say 1 and 2 it does not show all the elements of the list, and each time i ran the code i got different result.

Here is the output with thread count 1.

```
Thread-1 11
Thread-1 33
Thread-1 55
```

I ran again with 1 thread only, this time result is different

```
Thread-1 11
Thread-1 33
Thread-1 55
Thread-1 77
Thread-1 99
Thread-1 222
Thread-1 444
Thread-1 666
Thread-1 888
Thread-1 1111
Thread-1 44444
```

I am not sure about this behavior, how this is working.
Similarly if i use 4 the result is quite what i except, all elements are displayed and not repeated.

Comment: i would avoid relying using print for threaded output, since you'll get garbled/random output because of internal buffering/locking. Store results in a list per thread and gather them later.

Comment: That is fine but my main concern is that, if i use 1 thread or any thread count the end result should have all the elements of list traversed, which is not happening if i use 1, 2 or 3 thread count and i have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get what you want to do, major flaw was you assume size of p won't change locally for "work" function, but it's global and you remove elements from it:

```
import threading

p = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999,1111,22222,44444,566666,877889528]

# work the whole list as fast as possible
def work():
    while len(p):
        elem = p.pop(0)
        print (threading.current_thread().name, elem )

# or do same job in parallel n times.
def work_p():
    local_p = list(p)
    while len(local_p):
        elem = local_p.pop(0)
        print (threading.current_thread().name, elem )


class Runner:
    def __init__(self, thread_count):
        self.thr = []
        for _ in range(thread_count):
            t = threading.Thread(target = work)
            t.daemon  = True
            t.start()
            self.thr.append( t )

    def join(self):
        for th in self.thr:
            th.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #use n threads
    Runner(4).join()
```

Comment: i got your code, but it is only using 2 threads, i tried increasing the length of list and i also increased the thread count, but still it is consuming 2 threads. Any reason why?

Comment: i guess it depends on computing power used. first threads could already have finished the whole job queue before the last ones are started.